# Different Domains on Different IP's in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to use two different domains with different IP addresses, for example

```
domain1.com - 12.34.56.78 
domain2.com - 98.76.54.32
```

I am using **nginx** on Linux OS. What should I add in my nginx.conf?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to create two **virtual hosts** using `server` block.

Let's suppose `/var/www` contains `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` directories with whatever HTML pages, CGI scripts, ...

```
server {
  listen          12.34.56.78:80;
  server_name     domain1.com

  index           index.html;
  root            /var/www/domain1.com
}

server {
  listen          98.76.54.32:80;
  server_name     domain2.com;

  index           index.html;
  root            /var/www/domain2.com
}
```