# Nginx: How to set different IP for 2 domains

Tags: nginx

I have problem with set different ip for my domains, i read:

[Different Domains on Different IP's in Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498640/different-domains-on-different-ips-in-nginx)

but this solution doesnt work.

(I added new ip with command: ip address add 1.2.3.4/32 dev eth0 and with this ip FTP is working fine)

I set new IP in "listen":

```
    server {
listen 1.2.3.4:80;
#listen [::]:80;


root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
        set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
}
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

But when i ping domain.com i have still old IP.
Why is it not changing?

Comment: The link that you provided works only if you know the meaning of setting up two virtual hosts. what is your settings on `/etc/nginx/sites-available`? Basically you need to copy the `default` file to create two separate 'virtual hosts', each with different settings based on each domain.

Comment: I have 2 files: my_default - config first site and domain.com - config 2 site (the one I gave), but different IPs doesnt work.

Comment: Please provide the settings of the two files as part of your question. And where (directory) of the two domains located?

Comment: `ping mydomain.com` is unrelated to your `nginx` configuration. You need to look at DNS settings.

Comment: Domain1 config: https://anotepad.com/notes/j8tdmr Domain2 config: https://anotepad.com/notes/s3j8ke